# How to suppress SQL Server backup error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, smo

I am writing a powershell script that makes a backup of all databases in a SQL Server.

If during backup an error occurs I'd like to suppress the standard error message because I am handling the errors myself. I succeed in trapping the exception but the standard error message still appears.

How can I suppress the standard error message in the powershell script.

this is the code to do the backup

```
$svr = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $sqlservername
$dbBackup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
$dbBackup.Database = $dbName
$dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($FilePath, "File")
$dbBackup.Action = "Database"
$dbBackup.SqlBackup($svr)
$dbBackup.Wait()
```

and I trap the error with this

```
Trap [Exception]
{
    #error handling
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try what this author suggests?
http://arcware.net/how-to-suppress-powershell-errors/

Set the `ErrorAction` parameter to `SilentlyContinue`?

Comment: the error action doesn't work on `$dbBackup.SqlBackup($svr)` and the error appears excactly at this method